I have ERROR after clic on button with function
I have button who do functin
Function:
methods: {
        addToCard(object) {
                    object = this.objects[isAdded];
                if (!object == false) {
                    console.log("isAdded");
                    object.isAdded = true;
                } else {
                    console.log("is not Added");
                    object.isAdded = false;
                }
        }
    }
};


And data objects:
    data() {
        return {
            objects: [
                { text: "test", price: 50, ImgUrl: "/images.png", isAdded: false },
                { text: "test2", price: 60, ImgUrl: "/images.png", isAdded: false },
                { text: "test3", price: 70, ImgUrl: "/images.png", isAdded: false },
                { text: "test4", price: 80, ImgUrl: "/images.png", isAdded: false },
                { text: "test5", price: 90, ImgUrl: "/images.png", isAdded: false },
            ],
        };
    },

when I click on the button <Button @click="addToCard(object)">add</Button>
I have a Error in console
Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.addToCard is not a function
    NuxtJS 4
        0
        callWithErrorHandling
        callWithAsyncErrorHandling
        invoker

I did read MDN web docs but I don't find what I need

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem, the snippets don't help to see what's going on. addToCard method should be defined in the same component where  is used. The error suggests it isn't. The error mentions Nuxt, it's unknown if it's relevant

How do you using the method?
